# Elementor Pro: Change or remove category/tag/author prefix from Archive Title

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor Pro to build my page templates, and I have changed the tags labels to 'topics' using the functions below – this works everywhere except in the Elementor Archive Title widget (which is made through a regular Title widget with the dynamic tag set to 'Archive Title').

Here are my functions to change tags to topics:

```
      // Change tags to topics

function wd_hierarchical_tags_register() {

  // Maintain the built-in rewrite functionality of WordPress tags

  global $wp_rewrite;

  $rewrite =  array(
    'hierarchical'              => false, // Maintains tag permalink structure
    'slug'                      => get_option('tag_base') ? get_option('tag_base') : 'tag',
    'with_front'                => ! get_option('tag_base') || $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks(),
    'ep_mask'                   => EP_TAGS,
  );

// Redefine tag labels (or leave them the same)
    
      $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Topics', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Topic', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Topics', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Topics', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Topic', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Topic:', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Topic Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Topic', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Topic', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Topic', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Topic', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate topics with commas', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove topics', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Topics', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Topics', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
      );
    
      // Override structure of built-in WordPress tags
    
      register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'post', array(
        'hierarchical'              => true, // Was false, now set to true
        'query_var'                 => 'tag',
        'labels'                    => $labels,
        'rewrite'                   => $rewrite,
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_ui'                   => true,
        'show_admin_column'         => true,
        '_builtin'                  => true,
      ) );
    
    }
    add_action('init', 'wd_hierarchical_tags_register');
```

Despite the above code, I'm still seeing 'Tags' as a prefix [on archive pages](https://primestaging.org/topic/investment/). I've also tried removing the prefix from archive titles, but this also has no effect on the Elementor title widget.

```
    // Remove default labels from archive title

    add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
            $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
            $title = single_topic_title( '', false );
        } elseif ( is_author() ) {
            $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;
        } 
    return $title;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'd be happy if I can either change tags to topics on archive titles, or completely remove the 'tags:' prefix from archive titles (I'd be fine with removing author/category/month/year too).

Answer (score 15):

In Elementor you control this prefix visibility in the 'Archive title' element settings. Click the little wrench icon and uncheck the 'Include Context' option.

Comment: https://elementor.com/help/woocommerce-archive-title-pro/
All my google searches turned up a bunch of hacks and custom plugins for this issue so I'm adding the elementor reference which I ONLY found due to your answer.

Comment: After one hour research I found your comment and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[You can find the option "Include Context" inside de element options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAzow.png)

Change it to false so the archive context prefix wont show.